Compute the cellular homology groups of a graph with three 2-cells attached
Problem .
Proof (a): Let's compute the homology groups $H_p(Y)$ for all $p\geq 0$ using cellular homology. The CW complex $Y$ is obtained by attaching three 2-cells (disks) to the 1-skeleton (the graph shown in the figure) along the loops: $d$, $b\bar{c}b\bar{c}$, $abd\bar{c}\bar{a}c\bar{b}$. The cellular chain complex is built from the $n$-cells and the boundary maps between them. Let's describe each group $C_p(Y)$ for $ p = 0, 1, 2 $.
$C_2({Y})$ is generated by three $2$-cells so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^3}$.
Similarly, $C_1({Y})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^4}$ as it is generated by the $4$ $1$-cells and $C_0({Y})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^2}$ as there are only $2$ $0$-cells.
Now, The boundary maps $$( \partial_p: C_p(Y) \rightarrow C_{p-1}(Y) )$$ describe how the boundaries of the $( p )$-cells map onto the $( (p-1) )$-cells.
First, $$(\partial_2:C_2(Y) \rightarrow C_1(Y) )$$ is where the first 2-cell is attached along the loop $$( d ), ( \partial_2(e_1) = d )$$, and the second 2-cell is attached along the loop $$( bc\bar{b}\bar{c} ), ( \partial_2(e_2) = b + c - b - c = 0 ).$$ The third 2-cell is attached along the loop $$( abd\bar{a}\bar{c}\bar{b} )$$, so $$( \partial_2(e_3) = d - c ).$$
Hence, $$\partial_2: \mathbb{Z}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^4, \quad \partial_2(e_1) = (0, 0, 0, 1), \ \partial_2(e_2) = (0, 0, 0, 0), \ \partial_2(e_3) = (0, 0, -1, 1).
$$
Now, for $$( \partial_1: C_1(Y) \rightarrow C_0(Y) )$$ we use the similar computations for $1$-cells and we obtain:
$$\partial_1: \mathbb{Z}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \quad \partial_1 = $$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
which is a $2 \times 4$ matrix.
Then it remains to just compute the homology groups which I get the following:
$$ H_1(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$
$$H_2(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$$
And finally, the kernel of $( \partial_0 )$, which corresponds to the connected components gives us
$$H_0(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}.$$.
$\textbf{Proof (b)}$: Now, part (b), we use the Euler characteristic (not sure if there is another way to do this rigorously). For $( Y )$ to be homotopy equivalent to a closed, connected surface, its Euler characteristic should match that of a closed surface.
The Euler characteristic $( \chi(Y) )$ is given by:
$
\chi(Y)$ = $\text{number of 0-cells}$ - $\text{number of 1-cells}$ + $\text{number of 2-cells}]$. So, $$\chi(Y) = 2 - 4 + 3 = 1.$$
The only closed connected surface with Euler characteristic 1 is the projective plane, but the homology of the projective plane is not isomorphic to that of $( Y )$. Therefore, $( Y )$ is not homotopy equivalent to any closed, connected surface.
Question: Can you check if the result I got is correct for part (a)? Is the proof correct for part (b)? Thank you!
Remark: For full solution, check the answer provided by Ben.

Hi and welcome to MSE! I've added the solution-verification tag since that's what you're asking, but unfortunately I'll have to quote the tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' I'd recommend just asking about whether the result you got is correct, and people will most likely also weigh in on the proof.

Also, I'm not sure why you think that your proof for (b) might not be rigorous (enough): There's nothing unrigorous about it.

@BenSteffan thank you! I just edited the last part of the problem. Let me know if there is any confusion about stating the problem.

Your result for (a) is not correct, but the error comes down to something silly: You've miscopied the loops for the attaching maps of $e_3$ as $abd\bar{a}\bar{c}\bar{b}$ when it should have been $abd\bar{c}\bar{a}c\bar{b}$ and $e_2$ as $bc\bar{b}\bar{c}$ when it should have been $b\bar{c}b\bar{c}$, and consequently you should have obtained
$$
    \partial_2(e_3) = d
$$
not $d - c$ as well as
$$
    \partial_2(e_2) = 2(b - c)
$$
instead of 0. If you correct these mistakes, you'll find that the image of $\partial_2$ is spanned by $d$ and $2(b - c)$, so $H_1(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 2$, not $\mathbb{Z}$, and consequently also that $H_2(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
There's another issue, this time with $\partial_1$, which however shouldn't have affected the computation: The matrix you should have gotten is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since $\partial_1(b) = \partial_1(c)$ and $\partial_1(a) = \partial_1(d)$ (also the order of columns is strange since $\partial_1(a) = 0$, i.e. the outer columns should be the zero ones, but I digress). Effectively your matrix describes the boundary map for the complex where the orientation of either $b$ or $c$ is reversed.
As for (b), the proof is quite nice and still works with the corrected homology groups.

Edit: I was asked for a full computation in the comments, so here it goes. Denote the left 0-cell in your picture by $x$ and the right one by $y$. The cellular chain complex complex of $Y$ has the form
$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
    0 \to \Z\langle e_1, e_2, e_3\rangle \xrightarrow{\partial_2} \Z\langle a, b, c, d\rangle \xrightarrow{\partial_1} \Z\langle x, y\rangle \to 0
$$
where I write $\Z\langle \ldots\rangle$ for the free abelian group generated by the elements in brackets (such that the elements in brackets form a basis), so that e.g. $\Z\langle e_1, e_2, e_3\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}^3$, just to make keeping track a bit easier.
It's straightforward to write down the differentials now: $\partial_1$ is the map given by
\begin{align}
    a &\mapsto 0 \\
    b &\mapsto y - x \\
    c &\mapsto y - x \\
    d &\mapsto 0
\end{align}
since $\partial_1$ sends an edge/1-cell to the 0-cell at its tip minus the one at its end. The $\partial_2$-differential you've already computed in your post, so with the corrections I pointed out above we get that it's given by
\begin{align}
    e_1 &\mapsto d \\
    e_2 &\mapsto 2(b - c) \\
    e_3 &\mapsto d
\end{align}
Computing the homology groups is now rather simple: We can directly read off that
$$
    \ker \partial_1 = \langle a, d, b - c \rangle, \quad \operatorname{img} \partial_2 = \langle d, 2(b - c)\rangle, \quad\text{and}\quad \ker \partial_2 = \langle e_1 - e_3\rangle
$$
and obtain
\begin{align}
   H_1(Y) &= \ker \partial_1 / \operatorname{img} \partial_2 = \langle a, d, b - c \rangle / \langle d, 2(b - c)\rangle \cong \Z \oplus \Z / 2 \\
   H_2(Y) &= \ker \partial_2 = \langle e_1 - e_3\rangle \cong \Z
\end{align}
Obviously $H_0(Y) \cong \Z$ since $Y$ is path-connected; this concludes the computation.

Let me end by remarking two things: Since you know about the Euler characteristic, you perhaps know that it can also be computed as
$$
    \chi(Y) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\dim Y} (-1)^i \operatorname{rank} H_i(Y)
$$
You can use this as a check sum for your computation: In this case, you computed $\chi(Y) = 1$ in part (b) via the cell structure, but if you use the formula above and your calculation in part (a) you get that $\chi(Y) = \operatorname{rank} H_0(Y) - \operatorname{rank} H_1(Y) + \operatorname{rank} H_2(Y) = 1 - 1 + 2 = 2$ which tells you that you must have made a mistake!

I did part (a) and I still got the same answer. Can you provide your proof of (a) writing it more rigorously? I just got lost in the words of your explanation, unfortunately. Moreover, you mentioned that one may not apply the Euler characteristic. Can you also show me the second type of proof for part (b)? I am not sure if I understand what you wrote. Thank you!

I will try to understand your proofs and after that I will accept your answer as long as it makes sense to me. Thank you, again!

@Gradmath Sure, I'll write out my calculation. There's not much to say about (b): If you calculated in (a) that $H_2(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, then you know that $Y$ cannot be homotopy equivalent to a surface: If there was a homotopy equivalence $X \simeq S$ where $S$ is a closed connected surface, then this would induce an isomorphism $H_2(Y) \cong H_2(S)$, but $H_(2)$ is always either $\mathbb{Z}$ or 0, contradiction.

@Gradmath I've added the computation, let me know if anything's still unclear! :)

so my computation for the boundary map $\delta_2$ is correct? Do you mind writing an edit (proof) for (b)? Maybe adding more details to your argument in the second proof of (b)? Thanks so much!

@Gradmath How could it be if what you computed for $\partial_2(e_3)$ is wrong (assuming you're talking about $\partial_2$; there's no $\delta_2$ here)? As for (b), there's nothing more I can say. The comment I wrote above is a complete proof, but what I wrote in the answer should be plenty. I don't know what details I could add to make it any more clear, so please be more specific.

I guess I am looking for a coherent type of proof in the answer for (b). But I will try to polish the proof. I was a bit surprised with getting $\mathbb{Z^2}$ for both groups. Thanks!

I think the computation for p=1 is not correct as I got $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z_2}$. Am I doing something wrong? Can you write your whole proof for (a) only?

The whole computation is in the answer already. If you have a doubt or question about it, please point out which step you're having an issue with.

can you modify / add the computation for $\delta_2$? Or maybe more details to both computations?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
